# Invalid identifier but I don't want to add other foreign keys to the tables but it's not letting me

Tags: sql, database, oracle, key

Getting an error at the bolded. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to add the other primary keys into the table...so how do I get this thing working? I need for the tables to reference DonType only, not the other foreign keys within the table donor.

```
 CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS
    (PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PROGNAME));

CREATE TABLE CAMPUS 
(CAMPNAME NVARCHAR2 (6) NOT NULL, 
 Q1 NUMBER (10, 2),
 Q2 NUMBER (10, 2),
 Q3 NUMBER (10, 2),
 Q4 NUMBER (10, 2),
 PRIMARY KEY (CAMPNAME));

CREATE TABLE LOCATED_AT
(PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
CAMPNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PROGNAME, CAMPNAME),
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (CAMPNAME)
REFERENCES CAMPUS 
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE DONOR
(DONNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
DONTYPE NVARCHAR2 (1) NOT NULL,
PROJECT NVARCHAR2 (15),
PRIMARY KEY (DONNAME, DONTYPE));

CREATE TABLE COMMITTEE_MEMBER
(CMNAME NVARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
DONTYPE NVARCHAR2 (1) NOT NULL,
Q1 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q2 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q3 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q4 NUMBER (10, 2),
PRIMARY KEY (CMNAME, DONTYPE),
FOREIGN KEY (DONTYPE)
**REFERENCES DONOR**
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE DONATION_TYPE
(DONTYPE NVARCHAR2 (1) NOT NULL,
Q1 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q2 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q3 NUMBER (10, 2),
Q4 NUMBER (10, 2),
PRIMARY KEY (DONTYPE),
FOREIGN KEY (DONTYPE)
REFERENCES DONOR
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE CONTRIBUTION 
(CMNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
DONNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT NUMERIC (10, 2) NOT NULL,
DATE_ NVARCHAR2 (6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CMNAME, PROGNAME, DONNAME, AMOUNT, DATE_),
FOREIGN KEY (CMNAME, PROGNAME) 
REFERENCES COMMITTEE_MEMBER 
ON DELETE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (DONTYPE)
REFERENCES DONOR
ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: I would use a `DONOR_TYPE` separate table, and make `DONOR` and the rest of the tables reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference only one column you can do it as the following:

```
FOREIGN KEY (DONTYPE)
REFERENCES DONOR(DONTYPE)
```

**But you can only reference columns that contain unique values.** So you have to change your primary key to only one column or add an `UNIQUE` constraint to your referenced table(column) with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE DONOR
(DONNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
DONTYPE NVARCHAR2 (1) NOT NULL,
PROJECT NVARCHAR2 (15),
PRIMARY KEY (DONNAME, DONTYPE),
CONSTRAINT dontype_unique UNIQUE (DONTYPE));
```

Comment: **But you can only reference columns that contain unique values.** - In general yes, but you can disable a UNIQUE Key constraint. Then multiple values are possible

Comment: Yeah I read that in your answer. That was new to me and it's really interesting. Can you reference to a disabled unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, but there is a major limiation, the foreign-key constraint must be also disabled. Maybe it does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A table can have only one primary key. But you can add multiple UNIQUE key constraints. If you specify them as NOT NULL, they behave the same like a Primary Key. In order to create a foreign-key constraint you must create a unique key (or primary key) constraint on referrence table. This constraint you can also be created as DISABLED, then you can also have dublicate values in it.